# How to reduce line size from center to start Angle using canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working on `R gauge` widget customization. Using canvas properties I have to reduce my `Gauge` needle size from center pin to Start Angle.

```
this.drawNeedle = this.DrawNeedle = function (value, color, index) {
var type = prop['chart.needle.type'];
co.lineWidth = 0.5;
co.strokeStyle = 'gray';
co.fillStyle = color;
var angle = (this.endAngle - this.startAngle) * ((value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min));
angle += this.startAngle;
if (typeof (prop['chart.needle.size']) == 'object' && prop['chart.needle.size'] && typeof (prop['chart.needle.size'][index]) == 'number') {
  var size = prop['chart.needle.size'][index];
} else if (typeof (prop['chart.needle.size']) == 'number') {
  var size = prop['chart.needle.size'];
} else {
  var size = this.radius - 25 - prop['chart.border.width'];
}
if (type == 'line') {
  co.beginPath();
  co.lineWidth = prop['chart.needle.width'];
  co.strokeStyle = color;
  co.arc(this.centerx, this.centery, 82, angle, angle + 0.0001, false);
  // co.moveTo(this.centerx-58, this.centery-58);
  // co.lineTo(this.centerx-43, this.centery-43);
  co.lineTo(this.centerx, this.centery);
  if (prop['chart.needle.tail']) {
    co.arc(this.centerx, this.centery, this.radius * 0.2, angle + RG.PI, angle + 0.00001 + RG.PI, false);
  }
  co.lineTo(this.centerx, this.centery);
  co.stroke();
} else {
  co.beginPath();
  co.arc(this.centerx, this.centery, size, angle, angle + 0.00001, false);
  co.arc(this.centerx, this.centery, this.centerpinRadius * 0.5, angle + RG.HALFPI, angle + 0.00001 + RG.HALFPI, false);
  if (prop['chart.needle.tail']) {
    co.arc(this.centerx, this.centery, this.radius * 0.2, angle + RG.PI, angle + 0.00001 + RG.PI, false);
  }
  co.arc(this.centerx, this.centery, this.centerpinRadius * 0.5, angle - RG.HALFPI, angle - 0.00001 - RG.HALFPI, false);
  co.stroke();
  co.fill();
  this.angle = angle;
}
```

};

[image]

Instead of large needle (from the center to the start angle), the needle should small in size similar to the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read my comments in the code

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const co = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = 200,
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = canvas.height = 200,
  cy = ch / 2;

//gauge starts at a1
let a1 = 120*Math.PI/180;
//gauge ends at a1
let a2 = 60*Math.PI/180;
// arrow angle
let a = -60*Math.PI/180;
//gauge angle
let R = 82;
// arrow starts at this distance from the center
let r = 70;
// the center
let c = {x:100,y:100}

// coords to draw the arrow
let x1 = c.x+r*Math.cos(a);
let y1 = c.x+r*Math.sin(a);
let x2 = c.x+(R+5)*Math.cos(a);
let y2 = c.x+(R+5)*Math.sin(a);

co.lineWidth = 5;
co.strokeStyle = 'white';
co.lineCap = "round";
//draw the gauge
co.beginPath();
co.arc(c.x, c.y, R, a1, a2);
co.stroke();
//draw the arrow
co.beginPath();
co.moveTo(x1, y1);
co.lineTo(x2, y2);
co.stroke();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
}
canvas {
  border:1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

#### Update

The OP commented: the needle should point the value in scale which will update dynamically. This is how I would do it dynamically:

I'm adding an input type range to change the value of the angle dynamically

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const co = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvas.width = 200),
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = (canvas.height = 200),
  cy = ch / 2;

// arrow angle
let a = aval.getAttribute("value") * Math.PI / 180;
//gauge starts at a1
let a1 = aval.getAttribute("min") * Math.PI / 180;
//gauge ends at a1
let a2 = aval.getAttribute("max") * Math.PI / 180;

//gauge angle
let R = 82;
// arrow starts at this distance from the center
let r = 70;
// the center
let c = { x: 100, y: 100 };
co.lineWidth = 5;
co.strokeStyle = "white";
co.lineCap = "round";
// a function to draw the gauge
function drawGauge() {
  //draw the gauge
  co.beginPath();
  co.arc(c.x, c.y, R, a1, a2);
  co.stroke();
}
// a function to draw the arrow
function drawArrow(a) {
  // coords to draw the arrow
  let x1 = c.x + r * Math.cos(a);
  let y1 = c.x + r * Math.sin(a);
  let x2 = c.x + (R + 5) * Math.cos(a);
  let y2 = c.x + (R + 5) * Math.sin(a);
  //draw the arrow
  co.beginPath();
  co.moveTo(x1, y1);
  co.lineTo(x2, y2);
  co.stroke();
}

drawGauge();
drawArrow(a);

aval.addEventListener("input", () => {
  // on input the angle of the arrow is changing
  let a = parseInt(aval.value) * Math.PI / 180;
  // clear the canvas
  co.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  // and redraw everything
  drawGauge();
  drawArrow(a);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
}
canvas {
  border:1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<input id="aval" type="range" min="-240" max="60" value="-60" />
```

#### Update 2

The OP is commenting:

> my min value is 40 and max is 700..... So I need to show the needle based on the value between these value range.

In order to do this I need to map the angle to those values, So I've added a map function and I updated the code:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const co = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvas.width = 200),
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = (canvas.height = 200),
  cy = ch / 2;


let min = parseInt(aval.getAttribute("min"));// min value
let a_min = -240 * Math.PI / 180;// min angle to draw the gauge
let max = parseInt(aval.getAttribute("max"));// max value
let a_max = 60 * Math.PI / 180;// max angle to draw the gauge
let val = parseInt(aval.getAttribute("value"));
let angle = getAngle(val) * Math.PI / 180;


//gauge angle
let R = 82;
// arrow starts at this distance from the center
let r = 70;
// the center
let c = { x: 100, y: 100 };
co.lineWidth = 5;
co.strokeStyle = "white";
co.lineCap = "round";
// a function to draw the gauge
function drawGauge() {
  //draw the gauge
  co.beginPath();
  co.arc(c.x, c.y, R, a_min, a_max);
  co.stroke();
}
// a function to draw the arrow
function drawArrow(a) {
  // coords to draw the arrow
  let x1 = c.x + r * Math.cos(a);
  let y1 = c.x + r * Math.sin(a);
  let x2 = c.x + (R + 5) * Math.cos(a);
  let y2 = c.x + (R + 5) * Math.sin(a);
  //draw the arrow
  co.beginPath();
  co.moveTo(x1, y1);
  co.lineTo(x2, y2);
  co.stroke();
}

drawGauge();
drawArrow(angle);

aval.addEventListener("input", () => {
  // on input the angle of the arrow is changing
  let val = parseInt(aval.value);
  let angle = getAngle(val);
  // clear the canvas
  co.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  // and redraw everything
  drawGauge();
  drawArrow(angle);
});

//a p5.js function
function map5(n, a, stop1, start2, stop2, withinBounds) {
  var newval = (n - a) / (stop1 - a) * (stop2 - start2) + start2;
  if (!withinBounds) {
    return newval;
  }
  if (start2 < stop2) {
    return this.constrain(newval, start2, stop2);
  } else {
    return this.constrain(newval, stop2, start2);
  }
};

function constrain(n, low, high) {
  return Math.max(Math.min(n, high), low);
};

function getAngle(val){
  return map5(val, min, max, a_min, a_max)
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
}
canvas {
  border:1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<input id="aval" type="range" min="40" max="700" value="460" />
```

Comment: my apologies I updated my requirement. The main thing is I need to reduce my needle size the position is not a deal.

Comment: But the needle size **is** reduced, Please run the code snippet. In my comments I'm using the word arrow for the needle

Comment: Yes I saw that, but here the needle should point the value in scale which will update dynamically. I have tried to set the value for moveTo and lineTo to change the size and I successfully did that. But I won't let the needle to move.

Comment: I've updated my code. Now I'm using an input type range to change the value of the angle.Please take a look

Comment: do I need to change the a, a1 & a2 value if I change the min and max value?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I've made some changes. Now the only things you have to change are the attributes of the input type="range" `#aval`.

Comment: Thanks you really saved my day :-)

Comment: When I tried to set minvalue = 40 and maxvalue=700, it is creating full circle instead of the original one.  How to fix that one with my min and max value?

Comment: Of coarse. A circle has 360 degrees. You want to set it somewhere between 0 and 360. Please explain me why do you need a max value of 700? Depending on your data you may need to map those values.

Comment: Yes you are correct here my min value is 40 and max is 700 as I said earlier. So I need to show the needle based on the value between these value range. That's why I tried to draw the circle using these value.